# How to restrict NSNotification to call methods multiple times in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter, addobserver

I am using `NSNotificationCenter` to send local notifications in my code  and working in both Objective-C and Swift. I'm posting notifications from Objective-C And receiving in Swift. But the methods that I added in notification getting called multiple times and added observer only in `viewDidLoad` method.

Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.serverCardSynced), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_SERVER_CARD_SYNCED), object: nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.checkForAutoSync), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.initateSync), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_CONTACT_ENTITY_CHANGE), object:nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.menuRemoved), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_MENU_REMOVED), object:nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.reloadAllCards(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_RELOAD_ALL_CARDS), object:nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.initateDownloadMyCards), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_DOWNLOAD_CARD), object:nil);
}
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    self.isSyncPending = true;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:NOTIF_CONTACT_ENTITY_CHANGE object:nil];
}

-(void)insertData(){
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:NOTIF_SERVER_CARD_SYNCED object:nil];
}
```

I added remove observer in my `deinit` but it is not even calling. How to stop calling multiple times.

Comment: remove observer in viewwilldisappear

Comment: I tried that but it is not even calling that particular method

Comment: I aslo post notification in application did become active so how to remove observer for that otherwise it is calling multiple times each time when i come from background

Answer (score 0):

```
//call this method in viewDidLoad
fileprivate func registerNotifs() {

    //remove observer before adding to make sure that it is added only once

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_SERVER_CARD_SYNCED), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_CONTACT_ENTITY_CHANGE), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_MENU_REMOVED), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_RELOAD_ALL_CARDS), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_DOWNLOAD_CARD), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.serverCardSynced), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_SERVER_CARD_SYNCED), object: nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.checkForAutoSync), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.initateSync), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_CONTACT_ENTITY_CHANGE), object:nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.menuRemoved), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_MENU_REMOVED), object:nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.reloadAllCards(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_RELOAD_ALL_CARDS), object:nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.initateDownloadMyCards), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_DOWNLOAD_CARD), object:nil);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
fileprivate func registerLocalNotifications() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.serverCardSynced), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_SERVER_CARD_SYNCED), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.checkForAutoSync), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.initateSync), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_CONTACT_ENTITY_CHANGE), object:nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.menuRemoved), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_MENU_REMOVED), object:nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.reloadAllCards(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_RELOAD_ALL_CARDS), object:nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(MainScreen.initateDownloadMyCards), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_DOWNLOAD_CARD), object:nil)
}
```

add above method in **viewDidLoad** and in

```
deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

REF : [Where to remove observer for NSNotification in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689989/where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification-in-swift)

Update:

Check you class instance if it already persist i.e 
in view when you are instantiating this view controller
you can do like this

```
if let vc = yourNotificationViewCointrollerObj {
    // USE EXISTING ONE
} else {
    // CREATE NEW INSTANCE
}
```

Comment: In which class you are calling this view controll i.e mainscreen one

Comment: in mainscreen itself

Answer (score 0):

NSNotificationCenter is a "publish-subscribe" mechanism where each posted notification is delivered to all subscribers (called observers). If you receive a notification multiple times it means that either you have multiple subscribers, or you are sending a notification multiple times.

I assume that you have only one subscriber for each notification type - your MainScreen UIViewController in Swift. It means that you probably send each notification multiple times.

For example `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called multiple times (each time the app becomes active). If you want to stop responding to this notification after the first time, you could unsubscribe from it as soon as you receive it first time:

```
@objc
func initateSync {
    // do something first time
    // ...

    // unsubscribe to not receive it anymore
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: NOTIF_CONTACT_ENTITY_CHANGE),
        object: nil)    
}
```

This is what you do in real world after receiving a newspaper trial that you didn't like :)