# remove observers from all VC - swift

Tags: swift

in example : in `A vc` i added observer :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceive(_:)), name: .didReceive, object: nil)
```

can i remove observer in `A vc` when i am in `B vc` ?

i tried this (in `B vc`):

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

but it didnt work

it's possibile to do ? or i must remove observer in same VC where i created ?

Comment: `self` in B _is_ B, so it can never remove A. You need to store your A vc instance somewhere, and call `.removeObserver(aInstance)`

Comment: In BVC, `self` is not AVC instance. What about doing `addObserver()` in `viewDidAppear()`, and `removeObserver()` in `viewDidDisappear()`?

Comment: @Larme Maybe he doesn't want to remove observer in `AVC`'s `viewDidDisappear` and want to remove the observer from `BVC` after some action is performed

Comment: @Gereon something like this (in B VC ): `let main = UIStoryboard(name: "A", bundle: nil)
                        let viewcontroller = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AVC")
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(viewcontroller)` ?

Comment: @alexking No. You are creating new instance of `AVC`. You should get the exising instance of `AVC`

Comment: @RajeshKumarR so i must create global var type of `ViewController` and in `AVC `must assign `global var (must be name) = self` 
and in `BVC` `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(global var (must be name))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the instance of `AVC` from the navigation controller's view controllers property and remove the observer.

//BVC

```
if let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is AVC }) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(vc)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a piece of line in the viewController where the observer was added

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

this will remove the observer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40339926/10687271
As of iOS 9 (and OS X 10.11), you don't need to remove observers yourself, if you're not using block based observers though. The system will do it for you, since it uses zeroing-weak references for observers, where it can.