# Do I have to remove in built observers in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsnotificationcenter

So I have a login page that has a video looping in the background and I have done this with the following code:

```
videoPlayer.play()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: videoPlayer.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.videoPlayer?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            self?.videoPlayer?.play()
        }
```

Question is do I have to remove this observer at deinit or something and if so how do I go about removing the .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime observer. Not sure of the syntax when it comes to removing these built in observers.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift automatically deinitializes built in observables when the controller is dismissed - just use the following function.

```
deinit {
    // Release all resources
    // perform the deinitialization
}
```

there is also a similar question asked [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689989/where-to-remove-observer-for-nsnotification-in-swift/28690020)

[Swift deinit](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Deinitialization.html)